# How do I use a clipping path in transloadit?

Tags: image-clipping, transloadit

In the transloadit docs it mentions a parameter for the clipping path but I can't find any examples of how to actually use that.

See https://transloadit.com/docs/conversion-robots#image-manipulation-robots and look for the "clip" parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set `clip` to `true`, then it will act as a toggle (automatically taking the first clipping). If you set it to a string it's the name for when there are multiple clippings in an image. Other operations in the step, then only apply to the selected clipping.

Comment: What is a clipping in an image?

Comment: By that I meant a clipping path. A selection already made inside the image to which imagemagick operations are applied once you enable `clip`.

Comment: What tool do you use to define a clipping path, then?  Is this a photoshop thing?

Comment: We had one customer set the paths in illustrator. We would then process the paths already set. We currently don't have means to set paths programatically. It would be quite hard finding a pleasant abstraction for this. And we haven't had many requests for such a feature either. That said, we're open cool ideas around this.